# Web scraping and python data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Web Scraping script using BeautifulSoup4 and Python 3.0
I want to remove the $ sign (in result) from price value, make it of type float and perform some numeric operation on it. But it is in text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def bitcoin_scheduler():
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    offline_data = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(offline_data, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find('small', attrs={'class': 'bold hidden-xs'})
    name = name_box.text.strip()

    price_box = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'text-large'})
    price = price_box.text.strip()

    print(time.ctime(), name, price)
    threading.Timer(5.0, bitcoin_scheduler).start()

bitcoin_scheduler()
```

Result:

```
Wed Nov 15 16:37:20 2017 (BTC) $6962.29
Wed Nov 15 16:37:25 2017 (BTC) $6962.29
Wed Nov 15 16:37:31 2017 (BTC) $6962.29
Wed Nov 15 16:37:36 2017 (BTC) $6962.29
```

Comment: This is a story, not a question. What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: Might help https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example:

```
temp = "$6962.29"
temp = temp.strip("$")  # Removes $ from both sides
temp = float(temp)      # Converts to float
temp += 2               # Adding 2
print(temp)
```

It should give 6264.29 as output, because we've added 2 to the number.

Answer (score 1):

> You can check with `isdigit()` but default `isdigit()` method only
>   works for int not for float so you can define your own `isdigit()`
>   which will work for both:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import threading

new=[]

def isdigit(d):
    try:
        float(d)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def bitcoin_scheduler():
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    offline_data = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(offline_data, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find('small', attrs={'class': 'bold hidden-xs'})
    name = name_box.text.strip()

    price_box = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'text-large'})
    price = price_box.text.strip('$')
    if isdigit(price)==True:
        price=float(price)
        #do your stuff with price
        print(time.ctime(), name,price)
        print(type(price))


    threading.Timer(5.0, bitcoin_scheduler).start()

bitcoin_scheduler()
```

output:

```
Wed Nov 15 17:07:22 2017 (BTC) 7003.54
<class 'float'>
Wed Nov 15 17:07:54 2017 (BTC) 7003.54
<class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace() method, alternatively use the strip() method

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def bitcoin_scheduler():
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    offline_data = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(offline_data, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find('small', attrs={'class': 'bold hidden-xs'})
    name = name_box.text.strip()

    price_box = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'text-large'})
    price = price_box.text.strip()

    print(time.ctime(), name, price.replace('$',''))
    threading.Timer(5.0, bitcoin_scheduler).start()

bitcoin_scheduler()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your price is in the format "$100.00", then to remove the dollar symbol you can simply do:

```
price = price[1:]
```

This would make "$100.00" into "100.00" - It strips the first character off the string.

To convert to a float:

```
price = float(price)
```

Altogether it would simply be:

```
price = float(price[1:])
```

It may be worth performing some error checking on top of that.